# Hive CLI option -f not working when error occur

Tags: hive, command-line-interface

I have one file with many load data local sqls,which may contains sqls that can cause error from hive cli.
After error the cli stop proceeding the rest sqls.
If I want to ignore these errors,and continue these sqls,How can I do?

Comment: now I have to copy these lines and copy to execute by hand,but if in the future,this is an auto-daily-run script.So, can anyone help get through?Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**set hive.cli.errors.ignore=true;**

---

**Demo**

```
hive -f <(echo 'select x;select 1+1 as x')
```

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:7 Invalid table alias
>   or column reference 'x': (possible column names are: )

---

```
hive --hiveconf hive.cli.errors.ignore=true -f <(echo 'select x;select 1+1 as x')
```

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:7 Invalid table alias
>   or column reference 'x': (possible column names are: )
>   OK
>   2